# im2txt: Load input images from memory (instead of read from disk)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I'm interested in modifying [the tensorflow implementation of Show and Tell](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/im2txt), in particular [this v0.12 snapshot](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/f653bd2340b15ce2a22669ba136b77b2751e462e/im2txt), in order to accept an image in numpy form instead of read it from disk.

Loading a filename using the upstream code results in a python string after

```
with tf.gfile.GFile(filename, "r") as f:
    image = f.read()
```

in `run_inference.py` which is then turned into an ndarray of no shape. However, I can't replicate that.

I've tried the following:

## Loading the numpy array directly

I wrote this function to load a pillow image from a filename, convert the image to a numpy array and feed it to the `beam_search` function in `run_inference.py`

```
def load_image(filename):
    from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
    arr = img_to_array(PILImage.open(filename))
    return arr
...
captions = generator.beam_search(sess, image)
```

In this case, there is a size mismatch later, resulting in the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pmelissi/repos/tensorflow-models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py", line 107, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/pmelissi/miniconda2/envs/im2txt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/pmelissi/repos/tensorflow-models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py", line 97, in main
    captions = generator.beam_search(sess, image)
  File "/home/pmelissi/repos/tensorflow-models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/inference_utils/caption_generator.py", line 142, in beam_search
    initial_state = self.model.feed_image(sess, encoded_image)
  File "/home/pmelissi/repos/tensorflow-models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/inference_wrapper.py", line 41, in feed_image
    feed_dict={"image_feed:0": encoded_image})
  File "/home/pmelissi/miniconda2/envs/im2txt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/pmelissi/miniconda2/envs/im2txt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 943, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (960, 640, 3) for Tensor u'image_feed:0', which has shape '()'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can I somehow trick numpy into thinking the array has no shape?

## Converting to tf.string

Here I used the following function

```
def encode_image(filename):
    g2 = tf.Graph()
    from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
    with g2.as_default() as g:
        with g.name_scope("g2") as g2_scope:
            arr = img_to_array(PILImage.open(filename))
            image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(arr)
            return image
...
captions = generator.beam_search(sess, image)
```

This didn't work either:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pmelissi/repos/tensorflow-models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py", line 107, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/pmelissi/miniconda2/envs/im2txt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/pmelissi/repos/tensorflow-models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py", line 97, in main
    captions = generator.beam_search(sess, image)
  File "/home/pmelissi/repos/tensorflow-models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/inference_utils/caption_generator.py", line 142, in beam_search
    initial_state = self.model.feed_image(sess, encoded_image)
  File "/home/pmelissi/repos/tensorflow-models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/inference_wrapper.py", line 41, in feed_image
    feed_dict={"image_feed:0": encoded_image})
  File "/home/pmelissi/miniconda2/envs/im2txt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/pmelissi/miniconda2/envs/im2txt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 924, in _run
    raise TypeError('The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. '
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.
```

The last line in this stacktrace seems helpful, however there is no documentation as to what kind of structure is expected

```
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.
```

So, what should a valid input look like? The internals of preprocessing are not particularly clear to me.

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: [Attached gist of the modified inference script for the big picture](https://gist.github.com/PavlosMelissinos/9daa295d11af87848c3ea0778696eddd)

EDIT 2: 
The path to sess.run goes like this:

1: run_inference.py

```
captions = generator.beam_search(sess, image)
```

2: caption_generator.py

```
def beam_search(self, sess, encoded_image):
    initial_state = self.model.feed_image(sess, encoded_image)
```

3: inference_wrapper.py

```
def feed_image(self, sess, encoded_image):
    initial_state = sess.run(fetches="lstm/initial_state:0",
                         feed_dict={"image_feed:0": encoded_image})
    return initial_state
```

EDIT 3: I forgot to mention that I'm restricted to TensorFlow v0.12 and therefore I'm using [this snapshot of the im2txt repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/f653bd2340b15ce2a22669ba136b77b2751e462e/im2txt).

Comment: Feeding it as a numpy array is correct, it looks like you're not setting the size of the array in the model graph correctly (or maybe it was doing that before and with the changes is not doing that step now). How do you set up the graph? And what does the code look like when you call `sess.run(...)`? It looks like tensorflow just doesn't know what dimensions to expect.

Comment: [I've uploaded a gist](https://gist.github.com/PavlosMelissinos/9daa295d11af87848c3ea0778696eddd) with the updated code. Lines 93-96 are the only things that change behaviour. The code works when I keep 93 and 94 (original code) and comment out 95 and 96 but not in any other case. The thing is also that normally both np_val.shape and subfeed_t.get_shape() are (). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code:

```
with tf.gfile.GFile(filename, "r") as f:
    image = f.read()
```

has image as a python string.

Your code:

```
def encode_image(filename):
    g2 = tf.Graph()
    from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
    with g2.as_default() as g:
        with g.name_scope("g2") as g2_scope:
            arr = img_to_array(PILImage.open(filename))
            image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(arr)
            return image
```

returns a tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor of size ().

Presumably the function generator.beam_search(sess, image) needs a python string, and you are instead passing it that Tensor of size (). I suppose the quickest way to fix *your* code would be to do

```
return image.eval()
```

instead of

```
return image
```

But, I still have no idea why you're loading a jpeg, turning it into an array, then *re-encoding* it as a jpeg again.

EDIT:

If you're trying to really take a numpy array and turn it into a python string that is a jpeg binary, then you can use this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import StringIO


def encode(npdata):
    img = Image.fromarray(npdata)
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(output, "jpeg")
    image = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    return image

npdata = np.random.randint(0,256, (480,640,3)).astype(np.uint8)
print len(encode(npdata))
with open("/tmp/random.jpg", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(encode(npdata)) # Just to prove it actually _is_ working
```

You *should* be able to pass that directly to the line below with:

```
captions = generator.beam_search(sess, encode(mynumpyarray))
```

Also, here is proof that the original code: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f653bd2340b15ce2a22669ba136b77b2751e462e/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py#L72

```
import tensorflow as tf
def puregfile(filename):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(filename, "r") as f:
        image = f.read()
    return image
print type(puregfile("/tmp/random.jpg"))
```

That outputs "<type 'str'>", a *python* string, *not* a tf.String. But, I can't test it in full (or won't) because I don't want to download the model and mscoco etc.

Comment: "But, I still have no idea why you're loading a jpeg, turning it into an array, then re-encoding it as a jpeg again." I could have used a random numpy array but I decided to go with the same image that I used with the original code. However, incorporating the actual web service and data queue would have been overkill. So first I tried to load an image from disk as a numpy array and feed that to beam_search (which failed due to a shape mismatch). Then I tried to convert it to a tensor, which also failed but resulted in the "helpful line" that I mention after the second stack trace...